# Weblogic 12c include JSLT webapp library in ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl, ear, weblogic12c

I have an web application using JSLT and running in weblogic 12c. 
For now I installed jstl-1.1.2.war as a library via the console. In my weblogic.xml of my application I have this:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
  <library-ref>
    <library-name>jstl</library-name>
    <specification-version>1.1</specification-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
  </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I want to deploy jstl-1.1.2.war together with my own application war in 1 ear file so only 1 installation action is needed. Is this possible?